# Atom doesn't see R packages

Tags: r, atom-editor

I am setting up R in Atom, but when I try to load installed packages, Atom tells me there are no such packages.

The packages are installed via terminal, maybe I need to install them in a different place?

I run this line:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

And then this error comes when I try to run it:

```
Error in library(tidyverse): there is no package called 'tidyverse'
Traceback:

1. library(tidyverse)
2. stop(txt, domain = NA)
```

Comment: Have you tried rstudio?

Comment: Yes, the packages work there

Comment: But I'm specifically trying to get it to work in Atom